# Active Record join tables based on maximum date, then grouping by a different field and summing a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using ruby on rails with active record. I'm trying to join some tables so that I can group based on a parent class, but I want to sum up all columns on the child class for each user while only looking at the maximum date entry for that user. Very difficult to describe, here's the query that successfully gets what I want (except for limiting the result to only add the records that match the max date for the client's client interaction at that location camp)

```
@routeMeals = ClientInteraction.joins('INNER JOIN location_camps as lc on lc.id = location_camp_id')
                        .joins('INNER JOIN clients as c on c.id = client_id')
                        .joins('INNER JOIN locations as l on l.id = lc.location_id')
                        .joins('INNER JOIN routes as r on r.id = l.route_id')
                        .select('r.name, sum(c.number_meals) as totalNumberMeals')
                        .where('still_lives_here = ?', true)
                        .group('r.name')
```

What's left is I only want to get where 'created_at = [maximum date for this client_id and location_camp_id]'.

I've tried to use subqueries in here, but it keeps breaking

Comment: Can you please show the subquery you have tried

Comment: can't use max function like this `max('clients.created_at')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work, the inner SELECT inside the .where did the trick

```
ClientInteraction.joins('INNER JOIN location_camps as lc on lc.id = location_camp_id')
                            .joins('INNER JOIN clients as c on c.id = client_id')
                            .joins('INNER JOIN locations as l on l.id = lc.location_id')
                            .joins('INNER JOIN routes as r on r.id = l.route_id')
                            .select('r.name, sum(c.number_meals) as totalNumberMeals')
                            .where('client_interactions.still_lives_here = ? AND 
                                client_interactions.created_at = 
                                (SELECT MAX(created_at) from client_interactions 
                                where client_id = c.id and location_camp_id = lc.id) AND 
                                r.is_active = ? AND l.is_active = ? AND lc.is_active = ?', true, true, true, true)
                            .group('r.name')
```